# In a Makefile, how to update multiple targets with a single compile command?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have my .coffee files separate and I already use a Makefile to compile them into multiple corresponding .js files.  My rule:

```
tmp/coffee/%.js: src/js/%.coffee
    coffee --compile --output $(@D) $?
```

It looks like this:

```
$ make static
coffee --compile --output tmp/coffee/global src/js/global/admin.coffee
coffee --compile --output tmp/coffee/global src/js/global/ads.coffee
```

I would like to optimize my build process so that the coffee compiler is called once to compile all updated files in one go.  This is particularly important for a clean build.

So it would look like this instead:

```
$ make static
coffee --compile --output tmp/coffee/global src/js/global/ads.coffee src/js/global/admin.coffee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using `$?`, all you really need is to make the target depend on all the files. Maybe you want to keep a separate flag file, say `.built`:

```
.built: $(wildcard src/js/global/*.coffee)
        coffee --compile --output tmp/coffee/global $?
        touch $@
```

You will probably want to refactor your existing Makefile so you don't have any code duplication.

I'm assuming all your files are in `global` like your examples say, but not your existing code. If there are multiple subdirectories, you can't compile them all in one go (the `--output` parameter should presumably  be different for each).

Comment: It should not. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-g_t_0024_003f-944

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  I do need to do some work to adapt it to my situation (and my situation to it), but this is definitely the clue I needed.

Comment: @tripleee: You are right of course. I'm glad I phrased it as a question not an assertion ;-)